# In Thunderbird how go to directly into inbox when changing accounts?

Tags: thunderbird

Every time I change accounts in Thunderbird this page appears:

[image]

I just want that every time I change accounts it goes directly into the inbox.

How I can set this up?

Comment: How do you change accounts?

Comment: @JonasWielicki I just click with the mouse on the account name.

Comment: Why don’t you directly click on the inbox of that account instead?

Comment: @JonasWielicki Yeah, probably I should do that.